# Нужна ли запятая перед "сколько"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Прибор, показывающий, сколько израсходовано воды". Нужна ли запятая перед "сколько" и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. Это отдельное предложение.

Comment: Я бы внес коррективы: Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, начинающимся со слова "сколько"

Comment: Да, но это не спрашивают.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Ответ Виктора - то, чего я хотел получить от второй части своего вопроса. Может быть, вопрос был задан не вполне корректно.

Answer (score 0):

Очень интересный пример. Здесь что, придаточное предложение является частью причастного оборота?

Comment: А почему бы и нет? Главное предложение - односоставное назывное, а потом придаточное. Подобных примеров масса. Первое, что пришло в голову: "На форуме спорят любители языка, знающие, как ответить на сложные вопросы"

Comment: Да, не вижу причин для удивления.
А если бы это был "прибор, показывающий, сколько раз Петя целовал Машу"?

Comment: Удивляться можно было бы, если бы Петя целовал не Машу, а Сашу